# javascript using function passed parmeter in a varable after function

Tags: javascript

I'm still learning JavaScript so please forgive if this is a rookie question. Is it possible to use the value passed as a function parameter as a variable later in the script? This does not work for me even if I declare the variable in the global scope:

```
var parm;

function a(parm) {
  console.log(parm); //"Hello"
}

a("Hello");
console.log(parm); // undefined
```

This works of course...

```
function a(parm) {
  console.log(parm); //"Hello"
}

parm = "Hello"
a(parm);
console.log(parm); // "Hello"
```

I was just wondering if there was a way to assign a value to a variable from a function parameter directly.

Comment: Yes return the value from function simple :)

Comment: If every function call would implicitly spam your scope with the parameters of that function, keeping your local variables straight would be a mess. No, this won't happen *implicitly*.

Comment: I hesitated posting this question because I knew it would get downvoted, even though I could not find a simple answer to what I knew was a simple question, even after looking at several examples, and searching on Stack and Google. In any event, I hoping it helps the next rookie.

Comment: Such questions have already been asked  thousand times ,all you need is a patience and capability to search ,you might get mixed information and you have to sort it out that and that in the end will make things easy for you in future.That's how everyone begins:) Good Luck

Comment: Thanks @Shubh, I appreciate it. In doing my research, of course I added a return statement in the function, but it had no effect until I saw the answer below that added the parm = a("Hello"); would work after adding a return statement in the function.  It was not obvious to me even after looking at the examples, but it all makes sense now! So posting the question was worth while, but at a cost to my Stack reputation. Stack is just not forgiving of rookie questions, even when the op shows some thought and research, and that's a little irritating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways :

1st Way :

```
    var param;

    function a(local_param){
     param = local_param;
    }

    a("Hello");

    console.log(param); //hello
```

2nd Way

```
var parm;

function a(local_param) {
  console.log(local_param); //"Hello"
  return local_param;
}

parm = a("Hello");
console.log(parm); //Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the thing, you are atributing the value to `parm`, on the function call. So, the value is valid only **inside** the `function`. If you want to use the value other times, you need to define a value to `parm` on the declaring variable, like this: `parm = 'hello'`. Otherwise, the value is only valid inside the function.

Other solution, is changing the value inside the function, so that it returns the value you want. That way the variable is overwritten inside the function!

***Any questions, just ask!***